# $F $ is a homotopy functor iff...

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The following question was asked in my lectures of Topology and I am not able to make much progress on it. I am following Foundations of Topology by Wayne Patty's book.

> Let $\pi :  Top \to h Top$ be the functor which is the identity on objects and such that $\pi(f)= [f]$. Show that a functor $F: Top \to C$ is a homotopy functor iff there is a functor $\overline{F} : h Top \to C$ such that $F= \overline{F} \circ \pi$.

Attempt: If F is a homotopy functor, then I don't have any idea on how to prove the existence of $\overline{F}$ and unfortunately I am not able to make much progress on the converse as well.

Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: What do *you* mean by a homotopy functor?

Comment: @FShrike  Let $F: Top \to C$ be a functor.  If for all continuous maps $f,g$  if $f\simeq g$ then $F(f)=F(g)$ condition is always satisfied by this functor , then it is called a homotopy functor.

Comment: Did you mean, if $f\simeq g$?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, I mean the same.

Comment: Ok. Well, how would you begin to define $\overline{F}$? What is its image on objects? On arrows?

Comment: @FShrike Well , $\overline{F} : hTop \to C$. I hope it is clear.

Comment: You haven't understood me. *I* know how to define $\overline{F}$. I'm prompting you with specific questions to get you started. Any and all thoughts you have are welcomed and expected

Comment: Hint: Send $[f]$ in $\mathbf{hTop}$ to $Ff$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and then try to answer: Is this well defined? Is this a functor? Do you get a factorisation?

Comment: I just realized you have also asked the question about the 2-out-of-3-property of homotopy equivalences (for others reading this: math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627255). You need to use the lemma there, to show, that for the composition $[g]\circ[f]=[g\circ f]$ in $\mathbf{hTop}$ is well-defined, which will help you answer the first question.